# ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1170)

Tags: powerbi, azure-databricks

Getting this error when connecting Power BI with Azure Databricks through spark build in connector:-

> Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1170)
>   Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server
>   host and port specified for the connection are correct."

I have checked many times host and port of the databrick cluster , and also tried after restarting of cluster .

Guide for the connection:-
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/bi/power-bi.html

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem today. I followed [these instructions](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/ODBC-Connection-Error-Driver-Error/m-p/163966#M9750) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The user was not able to import SQL data Power BI and getting this error, while testing connection in ODBC was successful.
It turned out that he has old credentials stored in PowerBI, and that caused identification issues. Purging cached data sources (Power BI: Home >Edit Queries > Data source settings" resolved the issue.